# Partition help scheme

Tags: scheme

I have the following code, but when I run this example:

```
(partition 12 '(4 9 18 6 19 10 18 11 5 5 7 2 4 19 1 9 10 18 12))
```

I get

```
((4 9 6 10 11 5 5 7 2 4 1 9 10 12) (18 19 18 19 18))
```

in return.

I want it as following

```
((4 9 6 10 11 5 5 7 2 4 1 9 10 12) 18 19 18 19 18)
```

What should I do to change this? Thanks in favor

```
      (require (lib "trace.ss"))
        (define (partition pivot lon)
          (if (null? lon)
              '(()())
              (let ((split-of-rest (partition pivot (cdr lon))))
                (if (<= (car lon) pivot)
                    (list (cons (car lon) (car split-of-rest))
                          (cadr split-of-rest))
                    (list (car split-of-rest) (cons (car lon)
                                                    (car (cdr split-of-rest))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
(define (partition pivot lon)
  (define (partition pivot lon less more)
    (if (null? lon)
      (cons less more)
      (if (<= (car lon) pivot)
        (partition pivot (cdr lon) (append less (list (car lon))) more)
        (partition pivot (cdr lon) less (append more (list (car lon)))))))
  (partition pivot lon '() '()))
```

Dunno if this is a solution that you are looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

In some Scheme interpreters (Racket, for instance) there's a built-in [`partition`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/list..rkt%29._partition%29%29) procedure. Alternatively, it's also included in [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FilteringPartitioning). If available use it, it'll simplify your code:

```
(define (my-partition val lst)
  (let-values (((low high) (partition (lambda (x) (<= x val)) lst)))
    (cons low high)))
```

`partition` returns two values, the first one is a list of those elements that satisfy the predicate, and the second one a list of the elements that don't satisfy the predicate. It's easy to combine them using a `cons` to obtain the result in the format you want.

Alternatively, we could use [`call-with-values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-values%29%29), as suggested by @leppie :

```
(define (my-partition val lst)
  (call-with-values
   (thunk (partition (lambda (x) (<= x val)) lst))
   cons))
```

Either way, the result is as expected:

```
(my-partition 12 '(4 9 18 6 19 10 18 11 5 5 7 2 4 19 1 9 10 18 12))
=> '((4 9 6 10 11 5 5 7 2 4 1 9 10 12) 18 19 18 19 18)
```

Comment: Might be more concise to use call-with-values and just pass in cons as the consumer.

Comment: @leppie I guess it's a matter of taste, but I prefer my version, for me it's clearer. Anyway, I updated the answer with your suggestion ;)

Comment: I upvoted :) Maybe someone could not compile SRFI1 or have a decent Scheme ;p

Comment: @leppie come on, that doesn't make the answer incorrect! if someone needs a from-scratch working solution, they can use any of the other answers. My solution is practical

Comment: @Oscar I don't think your answer is really *that* helpful, since it boils down to "don't write your own partition procedure, use one that somebody else wrote". That's not very educative. If Scheme ends up as just another "don't think, just get to know your libraries" language then I would be quite disappointed.

Answer (score -1):

I find the recursive approach difficult, here's a simpler, iterative way:

```
(define (partition pivot lst)
  (let loop ((a '()) (b '()) (lst lst))
    (cond
      ((null? lst)          (cons (reverse a) (reverse b)))
      ((<= (car lst) pivot) (loop (cons (car lst) a) b (cdr lst)))
      (else                 (loop a (cons (car lst) b) (cdr lst))))))

(partition 12 '(4 9 18 6 19 10 18 11 5 5 7 2 4 19 1 9 10 18 12))
=> '((4 9 6 10 11 5 5 7 2 4 1 9 10 12) 18 19 18 19 18)
```

Comment: This might be an iterative _process_, but anyway it's a tail-recursive _procedure_

Comment: This is an iterative process, as opposed to the OP's recursive process. Both are syntactically speaking recursive procedures.

Comment: that's right, but that's not what says in your answer. You should rephrase the first sentence to explain it better

Comment: Oscar I'm sorry but I don't see what you mean. I don't use the terms 'procedure' or 'process' in my answer so I cannot see any contradiction.

Comment: Precisely, for a newcomer it's confusing if you state that a procedure is "iterative", but at first glance it's easy to spot a recursive _call_ in the code. That's why you should clarify that the _process_ is iterative

Comment: Again, I said it's an iterative "way", not an iterative "procedure". If the OP happens to be interested in this level of detail, the comments should then be helpful ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24980/discussion-between-uselpa-and-oscar-lopez)

Comment: Say what it actually is: "Here is a tail recursive solution"

Comment: Come on, it's not that difficult! It's an iterative process, implemented as a (tail-)recursive procedure. I hope everybody is happy now. Otherwise, I suggest re-reading SICP which explains it nicely.